# Jsonwebtoken Verify is causing a 500 server error in Express

Tags: express, jwt

I'm trying to verify/decode JWTs in my application but am running into an issue, and I have no idea why. Here is the function which is supposed to achieve this, but is creating a 500 server error:

```js
exports.index = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers.authorization;
  let decoded = jsonwebtoken.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
  console.log(decoded);
  res.send(decoded);
}
```

`req.headers.authorization` is correctly storing and delivering the Bearer token, and `process.env.SECRET` is the same key that was used to sign the token. I am importing the jsonwebtoken library. I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Just wrapped the function in a try/catch and the error that is raised is:

```
JsonWebTokenError: invalid token
at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/Users/-------/repos/sosh/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:75:17)
at exports.index (/Users/-------/repos/sosh/controllers/soshController.js:15:32)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/--------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/-------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/--------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/-------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/-------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/-------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/Users/------/repos/sosh/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
```

I'm wondering why it says invalid token - I use this same token in my JWT authentication strategy and it works fine. Its formatted as "Bearer j5asdj........".

Comment: What does your server logging / terminal output say? Have you tried wrapping this code in a `try..catch`?

Comment: The function does not even complete the console.log, the only feedback I get in the terminal when I make a request to the route which uses this function is:
 GET / 500 268.878 ms - 1368.

I haven't tried wrapping this in a try/catch.

Comment: _"I haven't tried wrapping this in a try/catch"_... do you think you could?

Comment: I just did and updated the question. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `Bearer ` prefix? `jsonwebtoken.verify(token.replace(/^bearer /i, ""), process.env.SECRET)`

Comment: @Phil thanks so much, that worked! I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't figure that out myself. Cheers.